# Update data in a WebForm

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm new in developing ASP.NET WebForms application. I have an application that works on WinForms. 
My main WinForm contains a control that after establishing a connection to a remote server, it receives values to visualise in the property Text of some labels in the Form. This control works in the same way in Running Mode and in Design mode as well (I'm using VS2010). 
I need to have the same control that works in WebForms. I re-writed the control for working in WebForms. I obtained the same behaviour that I had in WinForms but I'm not able to update/refresh the labels with new data on display. Where am I doing wrong? Why can't I see the changes on the display in both cases?

Any help will be welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: First welcome to Stackoverflow.com, second I think you need to show the markup and/or code behind. That way other users can locate the problem

Answer (score 0):

im not clear, which control you bind with, for example if you bind it with gridview you need to call `DataBind()` method after add/edit, or redirect page to load with fresh data

Comment: or just simply call DataBind() for the whole controls. That is if binding is used.

Comment: The control is a custom control that I implemented on websocket technology. It works using sockets for connecting and requiring data to server. I receive a data collection in the custom control and what I need to do is to update on fresh data the values of other control's properties. I would like refresh the webpage when I receive the socket callback. Using DataBind() method and forcing the load of page I can resolve my problem in running mode. What can I do for working in Design mode as well? I hope to have explained better my scenario. thanks